# Fermion as a mixture of particle and antiparticle

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

The solution to the Dirac equation (in the Dirac basis) are 4 coupled fields. The first 2 of them represent a particle (spin up/down), the other 2 fields are the antiparticle (spin up/down). When the particle is observed from its rest reference frame, the antiparticle solutions are zero. However once the particle is moving, all the 4 fields become coupled.

Does it mean that a moving electron is a little bit of a positron at the same time (in the given reference frame)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a "particle" is only a quantum notion which must be understood in the context of quantum field theory, as a asymptotic state "in" or "out", in some interaction.
So, classicaly, stictly speaking, there is no "particle"

You are speaking of the classical Dirac equation, which is a classical field equation.

The quantum field version of the Dirac equation, is an equation, where the fields are operators, and these operators apply on states. The "particles" are only some particular asymptotic states, in interactions, being on mass-shell. The field operators are mixing creation operators of particles, and destruction operators of anti-particles, because you cannot separate the two. So the classical version of the Dirac equation, which is a approximate view of the quantum version of the Dirac equation, is mixing too the degrees of freedom of pseudo-particles and  pseudo-anti-particles. But keep in mind that only a quantum treatment is correct, where particles are states, and fields are operators.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the solutions of the quantized Dirac equation. Basically the field operator has 4 components: the first annihilates spin up particle and creates antiparticles of both spins. The second component annihilates spin down particle and creates antiparticles of both spins. The third component annihilates both spin particles and creates spin up antiparticle. The fourth one annihilates both spin particles and creates spin down antiparticle. The physical meaning of this isn't clear to me. Why do we need to create and annihilate (anti)particles in this complicated fashion?

Comment: Also one more question: does your answer mean that we have only equations for the operator fields? But there is no mathematical description for the particle states? Do we consider the particle states only as abstract objects without any underlying details (such as a combination of the field operator eigenstates)? The thing is that the field operators should have some eigenstates, so the general state should be a superposition of the eigenstates.

Comment: @mpv : 1) If you look carefully at the definition of the quantized Dirac equation, for instance the formula ($5.4$) of this [paper](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/five.pdf), you will see that there are only $2$ possible polarizations ($s=1,2$), and the field is a sum about these possible polarizations, mixing particle creation operators of each polarization and antiparticle destruction operators of each polarization, so you cannot divide the field operator in $4$ components as you do.

Comment: @mpv : 2) Yes, the Dirac equation holds only for the fields/operators. A particle state is a state (say a "vector"), upon which operators/fields (say a "matrix") act. A general state, as usual in Quantum mechanics, is a superposition (and/or tensorial product) of basic states $|k,s\rangle$, indiced by momenta and spin. $\psi(x)$ here  is not an hermitian operator, so you cannot prove that it has eigenvalues

Comment: 1) Thank you for the reference. I am probably confused, sorry for that. My understanding was that the u and v spinors are 4 component entities (spinors, column vectors in spinor space). So this is not the case? Are u and v only 1-component objects?

Comment: @mpv : Yes, $u$ and $v$ here are $4$- (complex)component (bi)-spinors. However, the important thing is that each $u_s$ or $v_s$ corresponds to only one degree of freedom.

Answer (score 4):

Literally speaking the answer is negative. The charge of the state has to be always defined in view of the **charge superselection rule**. Thus for a particle described by Dirac equation, there are no things like coherent superpositions of electron states and positron states. A Dirac particle always stays  in a **quantum state** which is proper of  an electron or a positron, but never in a superposition of them.

Nevertheless the **quantum field** associated to these particle describes both  particles and anti particles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still not sure I fuly understand. I know what superselection rules are and it is clear that a superposition of electron and positron does not exist. But why the field equations mix these states? If these superpositions are prohibited, why the field equations for electron and positron are coupled?